# Getting an error while authenticating a user using AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

Here is the code I am using :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.6.10.min.js"></script>
<script src="aws-cognito-sdk.min.js"></script>
<script src="amazon-cognito-identity.min.js"></script>
<script src="jsbn.js"></script>
<script src="jsbn2.js"></script>
<script src="sjcl.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>

AWSCognito.config.region = 'ap-northeast-2'; //This is required to derive the endpoint

AWSCognito.config.update({accessKeyId: 'AKIAJMOWHTPNDMXG5OGA', secretAccessKey: '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'})

var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'ap-northeast-2_go0rGKVb5',
    ClientId : '6a0n8dqpi9i7be9mtve36u6klm'
};

var authenticationData = {
    Username : 'username',
    Password : 'Password1#',
};
var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

if ( authenticationDetails != null)
    console.log('Got Authentication');

var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

if ( userPool != null)
    console.log('Got userPool');



 var userData = {
    Username : 'username',
    Pool : userPool
};
var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);

if ( cognitoUser != null)
    console.log('Got cognitoUser');

cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
        console.log('idToken + ' + result.idToken.jwtToken);
    },

    onFailure: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    },

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting following error :

"amazon-cognito-identity.min.js:19Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hex' of undefined(…)"

I am using sjcl.js that includes the bytes codec that the SDK uses

Comment: This issue got fixed by moving following files up before including AWS files :

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried switching the order of the script tags? You might want to try matching the ordering given in the README.

```
<script src="/path/to/jsbn.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/jsbn2.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/sjcl.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/aws-cognito-sdk.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/aws-sdk-2.6.10.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This program worked by changing order of .js files as mentioned in above response.